# Mono winforms look different on linux

Tags: mono

I just ported one of my C# .net programs to run with mono on linux.  Functionally it seems to be working, however under linux the program looks very different.  It seems that many of the user controls have grown with respect to the main window, this results in a lot of truncation and scroll bars that are not present when built with visual studio.  I tried this:

http://www.mono-project.com/FAQ:_Winforms

but that didn't help.  Is there a way to make my program appear the same with mono/linux  as with .net/windows?  I realize that I may have to redesign the form slightly.

Also, since I loaded my .net project into mono I can't see to find the form designer?  How can I the form layout of my program linux side?

Comment: As Linux gave it's own HIG, I think it's quite predictable that controls are different sized and looks different. I'm not sure that there is a way to keep consistent look and feel between platforms.

Answer (score 2):

So the problem here is that if you make WinForms look like Windows on Linux, people complain it doesn't look native on Linux, and if you make it look native on Linux people still complain.

That said there might be bugs causing the UI to show incorrectly - you should try to create small test cases and file bugs (and in the process you'll likely find out what works on both platforms).

There is no form designer on Linux, you need to use Visual Studio for design-time support.